# Nodejs deploy em produção

Tags: node.js, deploy

Quais as melhores práticas para fazer o *deploy* em **produção** de uma aplicação Node.JS?

Gostaria de saber como é feito, hoje em dia, o *deploy* em produção de API's Node.JS. A minha aplicação encontra-se hoje *dockerizada* e rodando em ambiente local.

Também gostaria de saber se devo usar o Nginx dentro do contêiner e fazer o *deploy* do meu servidor nele ou simplesmente subir minha imagem Node, que já está rodando hoje.

Answer (score 1):

De modo geral, existem algumas boas práticas a serem seguidas, abaixo vou lista-las:

1) Build, se você está usando algum transpilador, como Babel ou TS, o recomendável é buildar para JS na versão do seu servidor.

2) Não utilize Process Manager, como PM2 ou Nodemon, pois eles gerenciam processos e abrem processos, recomendo que use Kubernetes ou Docker Swarm para fazer cluster da aplicação, são mais parrudos e eficientes nesse sentido, salvo se você tiver em uma aplicação de uma única instância de servidor.

3) tenha um loadbalancer

- No **Docker Swarm** - https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#publish-a-port-for-a-service
- No **Kubernetes** - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/
- No **Nginx** - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

4) Evite expor sua API publicamente, mantenha sempre exposta do Balancer pra frente,

5) Evite cluster dentro da sua aplicação, nativo do Node, ele tende a consumir mais recursos e gerar complexidade.

6) Faça uma URL mesmo que não exposta para o público de health Check, basicamente uma URL que checa se todos os serviços que sua aplicação depende estão disponíveis ou mesmo sua aplicação.

**Referências**
https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices#5-going-to-production-practices

Comment: Boa. Só complementado que não faz muito sentido usar Apache na frente do Node, faz muito mais sentido usar o Ngnix mesmo. https://serverfault.com/questions/286960/does-it-make-sense-to-reverse-proxy-node-js-through-apache